# Openlayers 3 drag event

Tags: drag-and-drop, drag, openlayers-3

I use Openlayers 3 for my mapping application. I need to identify, that a user moved the map. After a while of googling I found, that there shoud be "drag" and "dragend" events fired by map object. Unfortunately, it doesn't happen to me. I get only moveend event fired, but it's fired any time the map is moved - programmatic or user action. Please, could you help me with the issue? My code is:

```
function _mappingAPI() 
{
     this.map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map_cont',
                controls: controls,
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                        ],
                view: this.view
        });

        this.map.on('moveend', function(evt){
           writeConsoleLog("DEBUG move end",3);

        });


        this.map.on('dragend', function(evt){
            writeConsoleLog("DEBUG drag end",3);

        });


        this.map.on('drag', function(evt){
           writeConsoleLog("DEBUG drag",3);

        });
 }
```

Comment: There are no such events right now. Feel free to create GitHub issues for that.

Comment: The `pointerdrag` event might be the one you're after. However, it is also fired when the map cannot be dragged any further, e.g. because you are at the edge of its extent. Note that the `drag` and `dragend` events are OpenLayers 2, not 3.

Comment: Yep, pointerdrag works for me - I just found "miracle" of unchecking of "stable version" on the help page ... ;). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

user the control of Openlayers.Control.DragPan instead,just like follow :

```
var dragcontrol = new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan( {
            'map': mapObj, 'panMapDone': function ( evt )
            {
                alert( 'drag' );
            }
        } );
        dragcontrol.draw();
        mapObj.addControl( dragcontrol );
        dragcontrol.activate();
```

after drag,it will fire panMapDone event,and show 'drag'.

Comment: does not look relevant, as the question was related to Openlayers 3, not Openlayers 2